# React collapse row onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have data that I need to show in table, for all rows I would like to use collapse function. Now I have working code that is collapsing all rows on click, but in what way I can collapse only one already clicked?

This is my code:

```
class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datas: [
                {name: "or1", status: 11},
                {name: "or3", status: 2},
                {name: "or2", status: 22},
            ],
            expanded: [],
            isOpen: true,
        };
    }

    toogleContent(openIs) {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !openIs
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Table responsive>
                <thead className="text-primary">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.datas.map((data, i) => (
                    <tr id={i} onClick={this.toogleContent.bind(this, this.state.isOpen)}>
                        <td>{data.name}</td>
                        <td><Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen}> 
                           {data.status}</Collapse>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i gave the solution like you wanted it, with the indexes, without changing api data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **used their indexes** to find out if they are opened or not, but you can use their names too, or add at data object a key isOpened =>

```
state={
    isOpenIndexes = []
}

toogleContent(index) {
    // we check if already opened
    this.state.isOpenIndexes.find(openedIndex => openedIndex ===index ) ? 
    this.setState({
        isOpenIndexes: this.state.isOpenIndexes.filter(openedIndex => openedIndex!==index)
    })
     :
    this.setState({
        isOpenIndexes: isOpenIndexes.concat([index])
    })
}

{datas.map((data, i) => (
                <tr id={i} onClick={this.toogleContent.bind(this, i)} isOpened={this.state.isOpenIndexes.find(openedIndex => openedIndex ===i )}>
                    <td>{data.name}</td>
                    <td>{data.status}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is openedIndex fileld?

Comment: isOpenIndexes will hold all the indexes of the rows that are opened, and down i gave a prop isOpened      it checks if a index is in this array or not (i just gave it as a prop, but you can use it to style or anything you want).
Feel free to upvote, mark as accepted answer

Comment: but openedIndex is not declared and this code is not working. Similarly isOpened in tr causes errors.

Comment: openedIndex   is a callback you can rename to whatever you want ,    .find     .filter take a pramter i just named it openedIndex     (google for .find .filter)
THE code should work in theory, check for any syntax .
UNDERSTAND the logic and yo got it, you need to learn for .find .filter .concat